# Oracle SQL conversion functions

Tags: sql, oracle

Could someone please explain why this code

```
to_date('25-JAN', 'DD-MON')
```

works and this doesn't

`to_date(to_char(date_of_birth, 'DD-MON'), 'DD-MON')`

running

`to_char(date_of_birth, 'DD-MON')`

which is the inner function on it's own works, but the later throws an

```
"ORA-01839 error: date not valid for month specified".
```

Thanks

Answer (score 6):

Your code works fine with *25th January* as date. The problem is that dates need to have a year. So when you do this:

```
TO_DATE('25-JAN', 'DD-MON')
```

... Oracle needs to build a full date and assumes current year. Proof:

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(TO_DATE('25-JAN', 'DD-MON'))
FROM DUAL
```

... prints:

```
25/01/2011 00:00:00
```

Of course, there's a month that does not always have the same number of days: February

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(TO_DATE('29-FEB-2000', 'DD-MON-YYYY'))
FROM DUAL
-- 29/02/2000 00:00:00

SELECT TO_CHAR(TO_DATE('29-FEB', 'DD-MON'))
FROM DUAL
-- ORA-01839: date not valid for month specified
```

Comment: Great Thanks, i did a search(date_of_birth column of customer table in the OE schema) and found '29-FEB' which meant the error was as a result of 2011 not a being leap year, silly me. I am happy cos now i know what to be mindful of amongst other things when dealing with a date datatype column. Once again thanks.

Comment: @AndrewMudamai You are welcome. Feel free to tag the question as answered so it might help others in the future.

Answer (score 0):

You have an invalid day to a specific month in your table , 
for example :

```
SQL> select date '1996-01-29' + interval '1' month as col_1
  2  ,      date '1997-01-29' + interval '1' month as col_2
  3  ,      date '1997-08-11' - interval '3' month as col_3
  4  from   dual;
,      date '1997-01-29' + interval '1' month as col_2
                         *
ERROR at line 2:
ORA-01839: date not valid for month specified


    SQL>
    SQL> select date '1996-01-29' + interval '1' month as col_1
      2  ,      date '1997-01-28' + interval '1' month as col_2
      3  ,      date '1997-08-11' - interval '3' month as col_3
      4  from   dual;
    Enter...

    29-02-1996 28-02-1997 11-05-1997

    1 row selected.
```

look inside you table for invalid day of a month .

Comment: Thanks Nammari, i was able to find '29-FEB' in the column which i was trying to extract the data from. I would be mindful of this situation from now on.